# ui-router >= 1.0.0 get $transition FROM and TO

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In previous versions I've used $rootScope event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){}
```

Pretty straightforward approach.

But now I'm forced to use new `$transition` service. So for generic info I'm writing:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(to, from){
    console.log(from.router.globals.current.name);
    console.log(to.router.globals.current.name);
});
```

`from` is always empty and `to.router.globals.current.name` is it really correct way to get a `state` name now? :D

So, how I can get `from` and `to` names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the `from` and `to` like this:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition){
    console.log(transition.from());
    console.log(transition.to());
});
```

Comment: Thx. Is it just me or documentation is really crappy!? I'll mark it as an answer in 8 mins.

Comment: It really is (I suppose because they're still in beta). I also had a hard time navigating it. For reference these are the docs: https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/

Comment: Yeah, been there. Inner part of this "docs" looks like automatic documentation, generated from meta comments from code.